# Is it better to implement two classes or one class in the following case?

Tags: class, oop, object, design-patterns

I have a class "Vertex" with 4 attributes and a class "Vertex_" with one attribute. The one attribute in Vertex_ is also in Vertex. Is it a good design to keep the two classes or is it better to program just the class Vertex, although there will be 3 variables, which are not used, when I instantiate an object which needs just the one attribute?

Comment: I'd highly recommend to come up with a more meaningful name than "Vertex_" in code and maybe in the question above. It would also help to know the real semantics behind the problem, to know the meaning of the attributes. By default it seems to be an inheritance, but we also have a rule called 'composition over inheritance' which might be applied or not.

Comment: @pcjuzer Thank you for your comment.  In Vertex I have the attributes: Edges:List<Edge>, isStarter:bool, weight:int and predecessor:Vertex . In Vertex_ I have the Attribute Edges:List<Edge>. What would you recommend?

Comment: Yes, based on this information it seems that inheritance works here. I'd suggest to name "Vertex_" somehow else, maybe "SimpleVertex".

Answer (score 1):

Class Vertex_ is actually somewhat a duplicate of Class Vertex.

I would suggest using inheritance and having Class Vertex inherit the attribute from the parent Class Vertex_ while having the 3 other attributes Class Vertex_ does not have.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

This is a question that deserves a very long answer.There are two reasons for inheritance and the reason for doing it can depend on the language being used. One reason is for code reuse. Without knowing anything else about your situation, it would seem you are inheriting simply to reuse an attribute (but I suspect there could be more you will be reusing). But, there are other ways of getting code reuse without inheritance, for example containment, which is often a better way.

A powerful feature of object-oriented programming is the ability to substitute one type of object for another. When a message is sent to that object, the correct method implementation is invoked according the actual type of object receiving the message. This is one type of *polymorphism*. But in some languages the ability to substitute one object for another is constrained. In Java I can only substitute an instance of class `B` for an instance of class `A` if `B` is a descendant of `A`. So inheritance becomes important in Java to support polymorphism.

But what does it mean to be able to substitute a `B` instance for an `A` instance? Will it work? Class `A` has established a contract stating what each of its methods requires before you can successfully call it and at the same time states what each method promises to deliver. Will the methods of class `B` live up to that contract? If not, you really cannot substitute a `B` for an `A` and expect the program to run correctly. `B` may be a *subclass* of `A` but it is *not* a *subtype* of `A` (see [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)]).

In a language such as Python, inheritance is not required for polymorphism and coders are more apt to use it as code-reuse mechanism. Nevertheless, some people feel that subclassing should only be used to express subtyping. So, if `Vertex_` is only using one of the four attributes it has inherited, I am doubtful that an instance of `Vertex_` could be safely substituted for an instance of `Vertex`. I would not do the inheritance unless the language were `C++` and then I would use private inheritance.